# Connect same view in two different way with storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, tabbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm sorry for my english and my question is:

i have started to develop app recently and maybe my question is stupid.

I'm trying to develop an app with a tab bar, and in my "home" there are some images that connect (when are tapped) at the same view that are also connected with the tab bar.

To better explain my idea i attach the image of my storyboard where there are the connections (follow the link below).

http://www.manuelragazzini.it/mystoryboard.png

That works but the problem is when i connect the image from my "home" to the other view with a "tap gesture recognizer" and when i tap on my image it load the "label 2" view but without the tab bar, the tab bar disappears.

Why does it happen?

Comment: I guess You should implement custom segue class(subclass of UIStoryboardSegue) which will tell your tabbarcontroller to select view controller at index '1' (menu). Connect your image gesture with tabbarcontroller in storyboard and chose custom segue... Trying this in code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Create custom segue class (subclass from UIStoryboardSegue).

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSegueOpenTab : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CustomSegueOpenTab.h"

@implementation CustomSegueOpenTab

-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];

    UITabBarController *tabbarController =  (UITabBarController *)[src tabBarController];
    [tabbarController setSelectedViewController: (UIViewController *)[tabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]];
}

@end
```

src - home viewcontroller. You can refer to it's tabbarController property and get tabbarController object. Then just select item you need.

After You created segue, connect image gesture action with tabbarController in storyboard, chose "custom".

By the way, it looks like it doesn't matter which controller will be the destination of gesture action in storyboard, as we refer only to source viewcontroller(home).